# Web server that handles HTTP post json request

Tags: iphone, json

I'm creating an iPhone app and I want the app to be able to send some information in the form of JSON string over a web server/app (I really don't know) and display it in a web page or save it to a file. I know how to send the request from the iPhone, the problem is I don't have a clue on how to implement the server side and integrate it with a web page that can respond to the HTTP post I'm trying to send to it. I don't need any specific details so if you could only point me to the right direction e.g. reading material, websites, key technologies for this.

Thank you for your help

Comment: What is it you are specifically trying to do? And have you got any code already?

Comment: Im trying to send JSON strings (specifically coordinates encoded as longitude and latitude) to a web page that i can later download from the iphone, very simple stuff, I have the client side done(iphone side) using NSUrlRequest and HTTP post, my problem is where to send this request, obviously my own web page and I don't even know where to start looking how to create this web app that accept HTTP posts and update a web page or file.

Comment: do you already know one of perl, python, PHP, java, C#? If so which one? Or do any of those sound more appealing to you than the others? Do you already have a web server setup? If so which one.

Comment: I know java and  c# but I wouldn't mind learning python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general term for using JSON and HTTP is RESTful (actually that's not quite true, as REST doesn't technically mean JSON [though often it does!] and REST also includes other things, but it's still a good search term).

Here's a general set of links about the right kind of areas.

For python:

http://www.freenet.org.nz/dojo/pyjson/

For C#:

http://www.techbubbles.com/wcf/rest-based-wcf-service-in-aspnet-35/

For Java:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-137171.html

That should be enough to get you started; googling based on the various terms will throw up more articles. If you find any really good ones do add to your own answer!

Comment: Thank you, thats great I just needed some pointers to get started

Comment: @Mauricio Glad I could help. If you're happy with my answer you can mark it as "Accepted" by clicking the grey "tick" to the left of my answer.